# Moving the nth-child(2) to be first if the first child is an image

Tags: javascript, prepend

What i'm trying to do is first check to see if in an unordered list the first element is an image, if it is an image then either move the first child to be the second child or if it's easier move the second child to be the first.

```
<ul>
    <li><img src="test.img" alt=""></li>
    <li><p>text</p></li>
    <li><p>text2</p></li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li><p>text</p></li>
    <li><img src="test.img" alt=""></li>
    <li><p>text2</p></li>
</ul>
```

And then the finished result would look like this:

```
<ul>
    <li><p>text</p></li>
    <li><img src="test.img" alt=""></li>
    <li><p>text2</p></li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li><p>text</p></li>
    <li><img src="test.img" alt=""></li>
    <li><p>text2</p></li>
</ul>
```

How would I target the first list specifically and move that one without moving the second list? So only targeting the first unordered lists list item and moving it based on the if statement? I've tried using insertBefore but think I might be using it wrong?

Looking to not use jquery if possible and appreciate any help!

Comment: flexbox item order https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/order/

Comment: Any boilerplate for us to work off of?

Comment: yes https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/order/#article-header-id-1

Comment: please use a code snippet in your question.

Comment: @George Campbell: Sorry, I was asking Kuma.

Comment: sorry I thought you were OP, it's late!

Comment: Just checked back. I asked for some help getting this done with javascript sorry i'm not looking to use flex display in this use but will give it a try next time :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop through all the `<ul>` elements. Check if the first `<li>` children has an `<img>` tag. If it does then move first `<li>` after the second `<li>`.

Please review code example below:

```js
$(function() {
  $('ul').each(function() {
    var $first = $(this).children().first();

    // If first <li> has an <image> child
    if ($first.has('img').length) {
      // Move the <li> to second position
      $first.insertAfter($first.next())
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
    <li><img src="test.img" alt="IMG"></li>
    <li><p>text</p></li>
    <li><p>text2</p></li>
</ul>
<hr>  
<ul>
    <li><p>text</p></li>
    <li><img src="test.img" alt="IMG"></li>
    <li><p>text2</p></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: The asker mentioned that they're looking to avoid using jQuery if possible. Are you suggesting that this cannot be done without jQuery?

Comment: Thank you this works but if possible without jQuery. I'll attempt to move this into vanilla javascript but this is more or less what i'm trying to achieve

Comment: @Kuma Sorry I missed the no `jQuery` requirement, if is doable in jQuery is definitely doable in vanilla. There will probably be at least 2 or 3 loops to achieve the same result in vanilla JS. Honestly, there is no point on voiding the jQuery